# Building libgc fails on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard: ... and require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined

Tags: garbage-collection, compilation, osx-snow-leopard, boehm-gc

The following steps:

```
$ wget http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/gc_source/gc-7.0.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz gc-7.0.tar.gz
$ cd gc-7.0
$ ./configure
$ make
```

fail with this error:

```
In file included from mach_dep.c:163:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:42:2: error: #error ucontext routines are deprecated, 
and require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined
```

Comment: Disclaimer: This is just a note-to-self kind of question.

Comment: https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ucontext.h` is included here:

```
$ fstr "ucontext.h" # find string ...
./mach_dep.c:163
./os_dep.c:2752
```

Replace `ucontext.h` in `mach_dep.c` with `sys/ucontext.h`.

Details: [http://duriansoftware.com/joe/PSA:-avoiding-the-%22ucontext-routines-are-deprecated%22-error-on-Mac-OS-X-Snow-Leopard.html](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/PSA%3a-avoiding-the-%22ucontext-routines-are-deprecated%22-error-on-Mac-OS-X-Snow-Leopard.html)